# Change root password using a Bash script

Tags: bash

When I order a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server), I get a random password from them which I need to change.

I basically use [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6 x64.

I was thinking to make a Bash script which when I run will change the password of the VPS to a default common password which I would like to use with all my VPSes.

Is it possible?

I am thinking to use this inside the Bash .sh script. Is my code correct?

```
#!/bin/bash
passwd
echo jadaruine
```

If not, what should the code be?

Comment: I'm hoping that isn't your password....  Piping echo into passwd might work? `echo password|passwd`. Does mean your root password is stored in plain text in a script though

Comment: better add an SSH key and disable plain-text login.

Answer (score 10):

You want the `chpasswd` command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo username:password | chpasswd'
```

You might also want to look at `chage` for password expiry settings.

Comment: that should be chage, not change.  it is short for CHange AGE

Comment: @doghousedean thanks. That may have been autocorrected.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following to change the password on CentOS

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "jadaruine" | passwd --stdin user
```

Comment: I want to change the root password so will it change the root password or only users?

Comment: I mean I want to change the default login password of the root account of my VPS.

Comment: change the user to root

Comment: Working answer.